# Flask WTForm render selected with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

This is a really simple question but I cannot seem to find a good answer.

I have existing data stored about a user's selection and want to render that selection as selected in the dropdown.

```
{% macro render_bootstrap_field(field) %}

<div class="form-group {% if field.errors %} error {% endif %}">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>

    <div class="col-lg-8">
        {{ field(class='form-control')|safe }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <span class="help-inline">[{{ error }}]</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}}
```

And here is how this is rendered:

```
{{ render_bootstrap_field(form.gender) }}
```

It doesn't show what's selected and I cannot think of a way besides using jquery to add the class manually, but that would be a pain.

Thanks so much for the help!

Edit: forgot to include my view.py function! So I did set it

```
@app.route('/edit_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_user():
  form = UserInfoForm(g.user.nickname)
  form.gender.choices = app.config['GENDER']
  form.year.choices = app.config['BIRTH_YEAR']
  form.education.choices = app.config['EDUCATION']

  if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
     flash("submitting")
     g.user.nickname = form.nickname.data
     g.user.gender = form.gender.data
     g.user.education = form.education.data
     g.user.year = form.year.data
     g.user.info_complete = True
     db.session.add(g.user)
     db.session.commit()
     return redirect(url_for('edit_user'))

  elif request.method != "POST":
     form.nickname.data = g.user.nickname
     form.gender.data = g.user.gender
     form.education.data = g.user.education
     form.year.data = g.user.year


  return render_template('edit_user.html',
                         form=form,
                         user=g.user)
```

Problem found!

In case you are running into the same problem --- check your encoding! My unicode was throwing normal string off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not done in the template, you have to do it on the `Form` object before you call `render_template()`.

For example:

```
form.gender.data = 'male'
```

Comment: Hi Miguel! I'm a huge fan of your tutorial! Anyways I added some more details --- I did set it though in the view. It just doesn't show on the viewing part. I blame Bootstrap.

Comment: Are you assigning a valid value to the field? It has to be one of the choices, and also has to be the choice "name", not the "value".

Comment: OK found it! I had # coding: utf8 in my config file so the form was not recognizing despite the strings seeming to be the same : / Now it's fixed but it's ugly (need to convert int to string to unicode...) I'm using some Chinese so have to have unicode.

Comment: Why don't you use unicode all around? Your form class, templates and view functions should all be using the same encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Miguel is correct-- here's a complete working example:

```
#app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'Testing BS'

choices = [
    ('1', 'Alice'),
    ('2', 'Bob'),
    ('3', 'Carol'),
]

class MyForm(Form):
    name = SelectField('Pick Name', choices=choices)

@app.route('/', methods=['post','get'])
def hello_world():
    form = MyForm()
    form.name.data = '2' # lets set Bob to be active.
    return render_template('example.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the Template:

```
#example.html
{% macro render_bootstrap_field(field) %}

<div class="form-group {% if field.errors %} error {% endif %}">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>

    <div class="col-lg-8">
        {{ field(class='form-control')|safe }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <span class="help-inline">[{{ error }}]</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}

<form method="POST" action="#">
    {{ render_bootstrap_field(form.name) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Doobeh, turned out that the issue was with unicode, which I didn't include in the code sample. I'm sure others will find your sample helpful